# jQuery slider with hover navigation and pause - not using plugin

Tags: jquery

In my later days of writing jQuery as raw as possible, and not having loads of jQuery plugins stacking up and slowing my page down - I'm trying to create my own slider.

I have created a fiddle of how far I have got so far.

My HTML markup is not dynamic - and the slide animate process is positional only.

The complications I'm having is the animations have to fully run before the next animation can begin which makes my animations begin to queue up if you hover the menu lots.

I need an animation to stop half way though if the hover changes, and automatically run to the next animate position. Hope this makes sense, you will see what I mean in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYDtF/).

Also, I want the animation to automatically run through each slide and 2000ms - and if the slide itself is hovered, I would like it to pause.

I know I'm pretty much asking for someone to write me a custom slider script, but it would so helpful and intuitive to see how a raw one is written with out a plugin.

I need my slider to be lightweight, hence not generating extra markup. Like all the plugins I've tried just are to heavy and too much. I like plain jquery.

Any help would be sooo appreciated. Thanks

Please see my miniature fiddle example using the latest jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/EYDtF/

[image]

Comment: for the animation queue you can make use of stop(), I think what you want is something similar to toyota.ca homepage slider which I wrote awhile back. See fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/EYDtF/2/

Comment: I like the toyota.ca homepage - pretty much that's what I'm doing but with a cycle to. Thanks for your fiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sloppy but may help get you get started

```
var banners = $('.banner-slides'),
controls = $('.banner-menu'),
cycle = true,
current = 0;

doCycle();

controls.find('li').hover(function() {

    controls.children().removeClass('hover');
    $(this).addClass('hover');

    animate($(this).index());

    cycle = false;
}, function() {

    cycle = true;
});

function doCycle() {

    if (cycle) {

        if (controls.find('.hover').length > 0) {

            if (controls.find('.hover').next().length > 0) {

                var next = controls.find('.hover').next();

                controls.children().removeClass('hover');
                next.addClass('hover');

                animate(current);
            }
            else {

                controls.children().removeClass('hover');
                controls.children().first().addClass('hover');

                animate(0);
            }
        }
        else {

            controls.children().first().addClass('hover');

            animate(0);
        }
    }

    setTimeout(doCycle, 2000);
}

function animate(pos) {

    banners.stop().animate({top: pos * -200});

    current = pos + 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/EYDtF/5/

Comment: Dude thank you very much. Really appreciate. Can half get round what you've done. I've tweeked your fiddle with the hierarchy cause jslint was showing some warnings. Other than that, I wouldn't know if it's sloppy. Works fine. Tho I'm trying to get it to pause the cycle when the image area is hovered but not having much luck. Can you help? Thanks [http://jsfiddle.net/EYDtF/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/EYDtF/7/)

Comment: It's cool - figured it out. Thank you so much! - [http://jsfiddle.net/EYDtF/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/EYDtF/8/)

Comment: I seem to be having some trouble in IE, I just get this warning for some reason, can't figure it out. If I remove the script then page is error free. [http://imgur.com/VrwaH](http://imgur.com/VrwaH) - Don't suppose you can see why? [http://jsfiddle.net/EYDtF/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/EYDtF/8/)

Comment: Ok I've replicated the issue.. http://motocomdigital.co.uk/development/slideshow/index.php - so bizzare, I've used the script on its own, nothing on the page, as get the same IE error in all browsers now. Can't work out what the error means.

Comment: Sorry, ignore that again. I found the problem, I was still loading in a jquery slideshow plugin called bxslider - which was conflicting only in IE weirldy. Removed that a voila, works great now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at how these plugins that you don't like work. At the moment you hover function targets an id - if you target a class you immediately reduce the amount of code e.g.

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){

$bannerSlide.animate({
        'top' : var                   
    });

});
```

Then you can work out a way of passing the position (var) to it you reduced you code.

Comment: I think he used ID because the different px of animation, but of course you can include that in the html and grab it when you need it. Most likely he was not aware of the method to extract info

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I can see from your samples with how adding values to current css, and assigning to var instead of writing each position individual. @stevethere so simple if I didn't need to run a cycle.